# Eerror while opening exported html table to excel only in windows 7?

Tags: javascript, html, windows, excel, windows-7

i am using following code to export html table to excel , in Win XP and Win Server 2003 there is no error while opening exported excel file, but when i try it in win 7, there is some kind of error,

```
 function generateexcel(tableid)
 {
         var table= document.getElementById(tableid);
         var html = table.outerHTML;
         window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html));
  }
```

Info: there is one warning message saying we are opening a diff kind of file , that was k, but
       in win7 there is one more warming message saying (it was in some kind of chinees)....part.xlt.

**one more thing** its being saved with extension .xls.part.xls / .xlt.part.xlt , can we save with our desired file name ?

**** please let me know if any other ways for exporting html table to excel.

thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code written above is working well , cause of error is win7 has a mechanism that triggers this error , it's to provide extra security.

there is no issue in exporting html table data as excel ...